# ASP MVC view not displaying updated data when nullified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my ASP MVC 3 site, when a user selects a value of `Sole Proprietor` from the `Producer Type` drop down box, all values inside a fieldset by the name of `DSS Specific` are to be nullified and no longer displayed when the view is re-rendered.

When stepping through the code I can see that after the user hits `save`, the model object evaluates the `Producer Type` correctly, sets the appropriate fields to `null`, and when the view is being rendered I can see that the fields in the `Model` object are in fact `null` where they need to be.

However, the view still displays the values that were in the field prior to hitting `save`, and does so despite the object being passed to it conatining `null` values for those fields. I have also hit refresh a dozen times to make sure that page was not simply cached in the browser.

**CONTROLLER**

When the model object is first passed back to the controller, it is run through a method called `ReformatFields`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Monet.Models.AgentTransmission agenttransmission)
    {
        //redirect if security is not met.  
        if (!Security.IsModifier(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 1 });

        //Tax Id security
        ViewBag.FullSSN = Security.IsFullSsn(User);

        try
        {
            agenttransmission = AgentTransmissionValidator.ReformatFields(agenttransmission);
```

This is the code in `ReformatFields` that determines whether or not to nullify the specific fields. The model object is then assigned back to the `agenttransmission` object above in the controller.

```
        //TODO:  blank out DSS specific fields if not a sole proprietor!
        if (!agt.ProducerType.Equals("S") || !agt.DRMrole.Equals("Sole Proprietor"))
        {
            agt.C8CharAgentCAB0State = null;
            agt.C8CharAgentCAB0MktDiv = null;
            agt.CONCode = null;
            agt.BundleCode = null;
            agt.LifeRegion = null;
            agt.LifeField = null;
            agt.AGYMGMT = null;
            agt.INDSGC = null;
            agt.PENSGC = null;
            agt.GRPSGC = null;
            agt.LMKSGC = null;
            agt.LDT = null;
            agt.GCASBNS = null;
            agt.GCOMMSN = null;
            agt.GPROFBN = null;
            agt.INDSplits = null;
            agt.DSTSGC = null;
            agt.ANNCommCode = null;
            agt.LifeEAPercent = null;
            agt.VARPercent = null;
            agt.OwnerMaster = null;
            agt.LifeMaster = null;
            agt.CampaignMaster = null;
            agt.RelationshipEffDate = null;
            agt.RelationshipDistCode = null;
        }
        return agt;
    }
```

After being saved, the `agenttransmission` model object is then sent back to the view

```
                db.SaveChanges();
                DisplayPrep();
                agenttransmission.displayChannel = getDisplayChannel(agenttransmission);
                agenttransmission.FormattedReferenceNumber =
                    ReferenceConversion.UnobAndFormat(agenttransmission.ReferenceNumber, "S");
                return View(agenttransmission);
            }
```

**VIEW**

As you can see from the screen shot below, the `Model` object being passed back to the view has a value of `null` for `CONCode` and `BundleCode`.

[image]

However, the page renders with the same values as before .

[image]

And it is not a problem of the page caching the values as you can see here the HTML is actually being rendered with these values

[image]

Here's the actual code from the view for these two fields

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CONCode)
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CONCode, new { maxlength = 2 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CONCode)
    </div>

    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BundleCode)
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BundleCode, new { maxlength = 6 })
    </div>
```

I realize this is an involved process so if I'm missing anything you think would be helpful please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a POST all that data is stored in the `ModelState`. Setting the properties in your model to null and then returning that model in your view isn't going to blank them out in the view, because they are still in `ModelState`. You can either do a redirect to a GET action and persist this data in another way or clear your ModelState:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

The Html helpers such as `@Html.TextBoxFor` are pulling the data from the ModelState and not directly from your model class, and that is why the values still appear even though you set them to null.